# protractor : locating element inside Span tag

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I need to click on "medicine" which is inside span tag, code looks like

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <span>medicine</span>
           </a>
</li>
```

I tried with locators : linkText(),cssContaingText() but it didnt work. any other solutions except the usage of xpath ?

Comment: Define "it didnt work."

Comment: element(by.xpath(".//span[text()='medicine']/..")

Comment: Could you please post a few more lines of html code

Comment: Thanks Suresh for the answer, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you tried so far as it doesn't seem complicated.

Does this work for you?

```
$('li a.nav-link span[value="medicine"]').click();
```